# How to make the animation work properly every time the array is rerendered in angular animation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

So I have an array that have invoices
I render it this way 
Animation script:
[image: angular-typescript--animation]

Html:
[image: Html code]

the function that filter the array :

```
filterInvoice(filterd:string ): void {
if (filterd != 'all') {
  this.filterdInvoiceData = this.invoiceData.filter((invoice:any) =>
  invoice.status.toLowerCase().includes(filterd)
  )
} else {
  this.filterdInvoiceData = this.invoiceData; 
}
this.statusFilter = filterd;
```

}

When I am clicking on a btn to change the filter Its starting the animation but not "leaving" good

[link for gif-video of the problem](https://i.gyazo.com/52b83dc99fe5ca7160515626e5a37b55.mp4)

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz so we can debug it?

Comment: I edit it, go the the gif-video link

Comment: I understood the problem. I was looking for a stackblitz (if possible) so I can manipulate the code myself.

Comment: I don't know how to make it maybe can I give you a reposity?

Comment: https://github.com/Dor-Elisha/invoice-app.git

Comment: That will work but it's better for yourself to learn how to work with stackblitz. Search it. It's super easy and gives you the ability to create any project and share it

Comment: it gives me 404

Comment: type in console : npm  i
and then: ng serve --o

Comment: your link is a 404 page in github

Comment: you can try now I make it public

Comment: what are you saying my man?